# Convolutional neural network architectures with an arbitrary number of input channels (more than RGB)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am very new to image recognition with CNNs and currently using several standard (pre-trained) architectures available within Keras (VGG and ResNet) for image classification tasks. I am wondering how one can generalise the number of input channels to more than 3 (instead of standard RGB). For example, I have an image which was taken through 5 different (optic) filters and I am thinking about passing these 5 images to the network.

So, conceptually, I need to pass as an input (Height, Width, Depth) = (28, 28, 5), where 28x28 is the image size and 5 - the number of channels.

Any easy way to do it with ResNet or VGG please?

Comment: Are the channels RGB + 2 more (e.g. alpha) or are they a different encoding altogether? Is there a way of converting your 5 channel format to RGB?

Comment: @Djib2011, good point! I am sure it is possible, however I’m wondering whether it is possible to pass them directly as they are. For example, instead of RGB you use CMYK scheme (or any other).

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say **no**. If you want you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995977/how-can-i-use-a-pre-trained-neural-network-with-grayscale-images/51996037#51996037) answer, where I discussed about inputting grayscale images to pre-trained networks. The OP asked if it was possible to replace the input layer so that it can accept a different number of channels. I feel that this is impossible, because the subsequent layers have learned to extract features derived from this layer that is about to be removed.

Comment: @Djib2011 However in the link you provided the 2nd answer (not the accepted one) actually explains and shows that it is possible. However they are talking about a channel reduction instead of a promotion. Would be interesting if it would work somehow with increasing the channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrain the models, that's not a problem. Only if you want to use a trained model, you have to keep the input the same.