# Deep learning CNN network for CIFAR10 and FMNIST

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've written a code that trains and evaluates a CNN model on both CIFAR10 or FMNIST. The cifar works, but when trying to use my function on fmnist I get the error:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[4, 1, 28, 28] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Do you have any guess as to what's the problem? I am not sure what to do in order to fix it. I understand there is some sort of problem with dimensions or the way the data is being inputted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post the code for your model and the dimensions of the images you're feeding to the model this would be easier to answer. Try to make sure that the CIFAR10 images and FMNIST images have exactly the same dimension (height, width, number of channels) when you're feeding them to the model

Comment: I can post it but it's pretty long.. Another option I have is to use ResNet18 and modify the last layer to predict for cifar10 and fmnist

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand from your question you are trying to predict on a DNN that was constructed for input images with the dimension 3x32x32. If you try to input the FMNIST images you get a dimension error since the FMNIST images are only black and white and have only one color channel.
The model can't handle these images since you need to provide images with exactly those dimensions for which you have built the model.
I would not recommend to use the CIFAR10 model to predict on FMNIST due to this dimension misalignment and the performance will probably not be good.

If you want to use the model anyway, you need to reshape your FMNIST images exactly to the size of your CIFAR10 images.
First, you have to copy your FMNIST image 3 times to make 3 color channels. Then adjust the width and height by reshaping or resizing.

However, I would recommend you build a new model for your FMNIST dataset. If you want to use pretrained weights as an initialization, look for a model that is built for data with one color channel and similar image dimensions so that you can feed your FMNIST data to the model without changing the dimensions much.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I am doing an assignment that was given to me so sadly I have to use the same model for both of those datasets

Comment: I think your problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995977/how-can-i-use-a-pre-trained-neural-network-with-grayscale-images)
If you have to use the same model for both datasets, copy your grayscale images from FMNIST so that they have three channels and you can find the code in the first answer of the linked question. Then you should be able to pass them directly to your model without dimensionality errors